# Error in setup.py while setting up requests package

Tags: python, python-requests

```
Error:  File "setup.py", line 1849
    exec(f.read(), globals(), fficonfig)
    SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'configure_ctypes' it contains a nested function with free variables
```

I had been stupid in not changing the path and now getting aS under
Error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests': Permission denied

Comment: The `requests` package has no such line in the `setup.py`, nor does it depend on anything that has such a `setup.py`. Please show us the full log and commands that lead to the above error.

Comment: The error indicates you are trying to build Python itself, not `requests`. The line appears to correlate to Python 3.3.4.

Comment: Followed steps on this website: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install

Comment: At a guess, something is reusing the Python `setup.py` file (which has a custom `distutils` `built_ext` command), and that command is being fed an incompatible `fficonfig.py` file somewhere. The `requests` module has no such file. It has no extension build steps at all.

Comment: Can you please include the **full session**. It looks as if something is trying to install `python` into a virtual env. This is not `requests` that does this.

Comment: I had been stupid in not changing the path and now getting an error as :creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests': Permission denied

Comment: Problem Resolved !! Ty @MartijnPieters Had to just write sudo with wahtever i type in !

Answer (score 3):

Try folloving:

```
# tar xzf Python-3.5.0.tgz    
# cd Python-3.5.0
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
# make altinstall
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems you are not getting the permission .

Please use `"sudo"` command for whatever  you type